# signing assemblies with a strong name, ok, but what if some 3rd party DLL isn't signed?

Tags: c#, gac, copy-protection, assembly-signing, snk

I understand the basic idea behind signing assemblies but have a problem when using Telerik or 2rd party DLLs.
I have an .exe that uses 2 of my own .DLLs, the DLLs in turn make use of the Enterprise library DLLs and Telerik DLLs.

I gave all my projects a strong name .snk, but when compiling the compiler explains that the enterprise library DLLs, for example, aren't signed, which makes sense.

I don't want to turn off the verification with te sn.exe -Vr command or even delay sign my projects. But then how is this going to work? I'm grateful for any insight.

Answer (score 8):

It's inconvenient, but not rocket science to sign/resign third party assemblies.
Assuming you want to sign an unsigned dll like System.ComponentModel.Composition.dll with the default.snk key:

open the VS command prompt and cd to your folder with the unsigned dll(s)

```
ildasm /all /out=System.ComponentModel.Composition.il System.ComponentModel.Composition.dll
ilasm /dll /key=default.snk System.ComponentModel.Composition.il
del System.ComponentModel.Composition.il
```

In each applicable VS project, remove and add back the reference to your signed assembly System.ComponentModel.Composition.dll

Comment: Is signing assembly that is installed via nuget package recommended ?

Comment: Don't forget `/resource=somename.res` if the `.res` file was created by `ildasm`

Answer (score -2):

Yes, quite possible.

 [Here are the steps.](http://buffered.io/posts/net-fu-signing-an-unsigned-assembly-without-delay-signing/)

Comment: page not found.

Comment: -1 for linking to a resource instead of answering the question. Luckily, [there's a cached version of that page at archive.org](http://web.archive.org/web/20160604075757/http://buffered.io/posts/net-fu-signing-an-unsigned-assembly-without-delay-signing/).