# Why is Visual Studio asking for a strong named assembly?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio, assembly-signing

Because I am using an unsigned third party DLL I want to make all projects in my `VS2010` solution unsigned so I have unchecked "Sign the assembly" in all my projects.

When I now try to compile the solution I get this error:

> Unable to emit assembly: Referenced assembly 'MyAssembly3' does not
>   have a strong name

Why is this happening?

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15459816/third-party-dll-does-not-have-strong-name

Comment: See my post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15469534/remove-signing-from-assembly

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the assemblies to be signed, yet they are getting signed anyway, maybe you have the same issue I do [did]?

It turns out that it was referencing a "commonproperties.targets" file which was causing the sign option to be turned on no matter what I did.

[Remove signing from an assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15469534/remove-signing-from-assembly)